# Windows 10 Display Scaling Issues

Tags: windows-10, display, display-settings, scaling

I seem to be having some issues regarding Windows 10 display scaling feature ("Change the size of text, apps, and other items: x%" x being the percentage from 100% to 300%). Currently, I've set this feature to 200%. It makes me log out & back in to apply this setting; however, it seems that I've encountered issues with specific programs. It seems that some programs it has text, buttons, and other items all crammed together overlapping each other. Examples are,

AstroGrep at 200%,

[image: AstroGrep at 200%]

at 100%,

[image: AstroGrap at 100%]

CloudBerry Backup at 200%,

[image: CloudBerry Backup at 200%]

At 100%,

[image: CloudBerry Backup at 100%]

And then there are little things like this,

Sandboxie Settings 200%,

[image: Sanboxie Settings at 200%]

at 100%,

[image: Sanboxie Settings at 100%]

I'm sure I could find a lot more but I think you get the idea. How should I go about solving these issues?

Comment: Someone else may have an answer, but from my experience the solution is to get applications that properly support font/DPI scaling.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to get Inventor to look correctly on my system, I came across [this guide](http://www.danantonielli.com/adobe-app-scaling-on-high-dpi-displays-fix/). It seems to fix the issues with the scaling issues. The solution is simple, however, you'll see that you'll have to create a file for every application that you want fixed.

1. Open the registry and navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > SideBySide`.
2. Create a new DWORD (32 bit) Value with the name of `PreferExternalManifest`.
3. Modify that value from `0` to `1`

ok, now, go to your application and create a manifest file for it. So, when I open Inventor (right click on the shortcut and click "open file location"), I'm opening Inventor.exe.

4. Take the name of the application and create a new file with the `application name` + `.manifest`. Note: include the extension `.exe` so it'll read `name.exe.manifest`

So for me, I have two main files in my files in the directory:

- Inventor.exe
- Inventor.exe.manifest

Open the the manifest file and paste the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*">
    </assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT"
      version="9.0.21022.8"
      processorArchitecture="amd64"
      publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
    </assemblyIdentity>
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel
        level="asInvoker"
        uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>

<asmv3:application>
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>

</assembly>
```

Done, open up the application and see the changes.